# merge two trees adding only unique nodes from one tree to the next

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, merge, tree

I'm attempting to merge Tree2 into Tree1.  The merged result contains all of existing nodes in Tree1 with the addition of the Tree2 nodes, placed at the right level in the hierarchy, that do not exist in Tree1. The final tree inputs are larger and deeper but I've struggled with the simple example trees below.

```
Tree1 = {"name":"A","children":[{"name":"B","children":[{"name":"C","children":[]}]},"name":"B1","children":[{"name":"C1","children":[]}]}]}
Tree2 = {"name":"A", "children":[{"name":"B", "children":[{"name":"C2", "children":[]}]}]}

merged = {"name":"A","children":[{"name":"B","children":[{"name":"C","children":[]},{"name":"C2","children":[]}]},{"name":"B1","children":[{"name":"C1","children":[]}]}]}
```

Comment: do you want a new tree or add all to tree one? what about if the first level has name `x`?

Comment: Ideally just adding to the existing tree as I will have multiple trees (Tree2, Tree3, Tree4 ...) to merge in the final code.  If the first level has the same name ("name":"A" in my example), do not duplicate the name in the merged tree.  In this example there is only one top level "name":"A".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could merge by looking at the name propery of the same level.

This approach returns an array, because if you have different names for the root, the result contains at least two object.

```js
const
    merge = (a, b) => {
        if (!Array.isArray(a)) a = [a];
        if (!Array.isArray(b)) b = [b];
        return [...a, ...b].reduce((r, o) => {
            const item = r.find(({ name }) => o.name === name);
            if (item) item.children = merge(item.children, o.children);
            else r.push(o);
            return r;
        }, []);
    },
    tree1 = { name: "A", children: [{ name: "B", children: [{ name: "C", children: [] }] }, { name: "B1", children: [{ name: "C1", children: [] }] }] },
    tree2 = { name: "A", children: [{ name: "B", children: [{ name: "C2", children: [] }] }] },
    result = merge(tree1, tree2);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  My additional testing shows this, of course, works with the other trees I am using for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to merge your trees:

```
function merge(...trees){
   var m = {};
   for (var i of trees){
      m[i.name] = [...(i.name in m ? m[i.name] : []), ...i.children];
   }
   return Object.keys(m).map(function(x){return {name:x, children:m[x].length > 1 ? merge(...m[x]) : m[x]}})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We note the similarity of the collected list of children and the initial parameters of our function, and can end up with a simple recursion.  Here we fold the tree into an object whose keys are the `name`s, and whose values are  the collected children.  Then we call `Object .entries` on that and map the key-value pairs into `name` and (through a recurive call) `children` properties for each.  That's all it takes

```js
const mergeTrees = (...trees) => 
  Object .entries (trees .reduce ((a, {name, children = []}) => ({
    ...a, 
    [name]: (a [name] || []) .concat (children)
  }), {})) .map (([k, v]) => ({name: k, children : mergeTrees (...v)}))

const tree1 = {name: "A", children: [{name: "B", children: [{name: "C", children: []}]}, {name: "B1", children: [{name: "C1", children: []}]}]}
const tree2 = {name: "A", children: [{name: "B", children: [{name: "C2", children: []}]}]}

console .log (mergeTrees (tree1, tree2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Note that we return a forest, not a tree.  If you know that all trees will have the same root, then you can extract the first element from the result.